# Split file based on string delimiter in bash.how?

Tags: bash, file, split

I have this file.csv :

```
coordinate1,coordinate2,value1
11111,a1,65
11111,a2,32
22222,b1,39
22222,b3,55
33333,c5,12
33333,c9,16
coordinate1,coordinate2,value2
54656,a1,65
21342,a2,32
23543,b1,39
123123,b3,55
568568,c5,12
568568,c9,16
123123,b3,55
568568,c5,12
568568,c9,16
coordinate1,coordinate2,value3
23543,b1,39
123123,b3,55
568568,c5,12
568568,c9,16
123123,b3,55
23543,b1,39
123123,b3,55
568568,c5,12
568568,c9,16
123123,b3,55
11111,a1,65
11111,a2,32
22222,b1,39
22222,b3,55
33333,c5,12
33333,c9,16
```

Now I would like to split this file in 3 files , everyone whit only bloc of data

```
Es: 1° file
   coordinate1,coordinate2,value1
    11111,a1,65
    11111,a2,32
    22222,b1,39
    22222,b3,55
    33333,c5,12
    33333,c9,16

Es: 2° file
    coordinate1,coordinate2,value2
    54656,a1,65
    21342,a2,32
    23543,b1,39
    123123,b3,55
    568568,c5,12
    568568,c9,16
    123123,b3,55
    568568,c5,12
    568568,c9,16
```

Answer (score 22):

Blatantly stolen from [this forum](http://nixcraft.com/shell-scripting/8464-split-files-specifying-string-bash-shell.html):

```
awk '/YOUR_TEXT_HERE/{n++}{print >"out" n ".txt" }' final.txt
```

should do the trick (replacing `YOUR_TEXT_HERE`, of course).

Replacing it with your conditions, and sending output to `#file.txt` with an input file of `a.txt`:

```
$ awk '/coordinate1,coordinate2,value?/{n++}{print > n "file.txt" }' a.txt
$ ls
1file.txt  2file.txt  3file.txt  a.txt
$ cat 1file.txt 
coordinate1,coordinate2,value1
11111,a1,65
11111,a2,32
22222,b1,39
22222,b3,55
33333,c5,12
33333,c9,16
$ cat 2file.txt 
coordinate1,coordinate2,value2
54656,a1,65
21342,a2,32
23543,b1,39
123123,b3,55
568568,c5,12
568568,c9,16
123123,b3,55
568568,c5,12
568568,c9,16
$ cat 3file.txt 
coordinate1,coordinate2,value3
23543,b1,39
123123,b3,55
568568,c5,12
568568,c9,16
123123,b3,55
23543,b1,39
123123,b3,55
568568,c5,12
568568,c9,16
123123,b3,55
11111,a1,65
11111,a2,32
22222,b1,39
22222,b3,55
33333,c5,12
33333,c9,16
```

Comment: I tried this example. I get the following error: awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 /coordinate1,coordinate2,value?/{n++}{print > n >>>  "file.txt" <<<

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian Which version of awk did you use?

Comment: @Armali awk version 20070501

Comment: What if I would like split file in chunks containing x-times header (or some pattern)?

Comment: Is it possible to name the output files according to what `?` is? (e.g. `1`, `2`, `3` in this example)

Answer (score 7):

You could use csplit:

```
csplit file.txt /^c.*/ {*}
```

This syntax works on cygwin but haven't tried it elswhere.

Answer (score 2):

This differently quoted version of the other answer also works with Windows CMD:

```
awk "/coordinate1,coordinate2,value?/{n++}{print>n\"file.txt\"}" a.txt
```