# Python: Search Journal.txt for dates and write the corresponding text into a new file for Evernote import

Tags: file-io, python-2.7

I've been learning Python for a week now and am currently at Exercise 26 (learnpythonthehardway). So I know nothing. I tried searching but couldn't find what I need.

**What I need:
I want to write a script that breaks my Journal.txt file into several text files to be able to import them into Evernote. Evernote pulls the title for a note from the first line of the .txt**

This is a random example of the date format I used in my Journal.txt

1/13/2013, 09/02/2012, so I'm afraid the date is not consistent. I know about:

```
if 'blabla' in open('example.txt').read():
```

but don't know how to use it with a date. Please help me to elicit date corresponding Journal entries from a large file into a new one. This is literally all I got so far:

```
Journal = open("D:/Australien/Journal.txt", 'r').read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing it like recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825745/split-file-based-on-string-delimiter-in-bash-how/1825810#1825810) - replacing `YOUR_TEXT_HERE` with a search pattern for a date, e. g. `[0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+`.

```
awk "/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+/{n++}{print > n \".txt\" }" a.txt
```

If you don't have `awk` installed on your PC, you can fetch it [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm).