# split file into multiple files based upon differing start and end delimiter

Tags: regex, command-line, awk, split, delimiter

i have a file that i need split into multiple files, and need it done via separate start and end delimiters.

for example, if i have the following file:

```
abcdef
START
ghijklm
nopqrst
END
uvwxyz
START
abcdef
ghijklm
nopqrs
END
START
tuvwxyz
END
```

i need 3 separate files of:

file1

```
START
ghijklm
nopqrst
END
```

file2

```
START
abcdef
ghijklm
nopqrs
END
```

file3

```
START
tuvwxyz
END
```

i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825745/split-file-based-on-string-delimiter-in-bash-how) link which showed how to do it with a starting delimiter, but i also need an ending delimiter.  i have tried this using some regex in the awk command, but am not getting the result that i want.  i don't quite understand how to get awk to be 'lazy' or 'non greedy', so that i can get it to pull apart the file correctly.

i really like the awk solution.  something similar would be fantastic (i am reposting the solution here so you don't have to click through:

`awk '/DELIMITER_HERE/{n++}{print >"out" n ".txt" }' input_file.txt`

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk '/^START/{n++;w=1} n&&w{print >"out" n ".txt"} /^END/{w=0}' input_file.txt
```

Comment: i like this solution the best.  it worked perfectly for me, and i only had to type in the delimiters one time for the command (the delimiters are much, much longer than my START and END delimiters used in the example).  Thank you.

Comment: using n&&w is an amazing trick and it did all the job. Nice One.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '
    /START/ {p = 1; n++; file = "file" n}
    p { print > file }
    /END/ {p = 0}
' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another example using [range](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ranges.html) notation:

```
awk '/START/,/END/ {if(/START/) n++; print > "out" n ".txt"}' data
```

Or an equivalent with a different if/else syntax:

```
awk '/START/,/END/ {print > "out" (/START/ ? ++n : n) ".txt"}' data
```

Here's a version without repeating the `/START/` regex after Ed Morton's comments because I just wanted to see if it would work:

```
awk '/START/ && ++n,/END/ {print > "out" n ".txt" }' data
```

The other answers are definitely better if your range is or will ever be non-inclusive of the ends.

Comment: never use range notation - it makes the trivial stuff slightly briefer but then requires a complete re-write and/or duplication of conditions (as in this case) when things get even slightly more complicated.